# Quarkus Micrometer Gauge metric doesn't show or is NaN

Tags: quarkus

I am trying to expose a Metric stored in a Database through Prometheus using Micrometer's Gauge.

I can't make it work.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class OperationalMetricsBO {

    private final String METIC_NAME_PREFIX = "telecomandament.ticketing.api.";
    private final String METRIC_NAME_SALES_BY_PAYMENT_MODE = METIC_NAME_PREFIX+"sales.by.payment.mode";
    private final MeterRegistry registry;
    
    
    Integer metricSalesByPaymentModeEfectiu;
    Integer metricSalesByPaymentModeTargeta;
    

    public OperationalMetricsBO(MeterRegistry registry){
        this.registry = registry;
    }   
    
    public Integer getMetricSalesByPaymentModeEfectiu() {
        return metricSalesByPaymentModeEfectiu;
    }


    public Integer getMetricSalesByPaymentModeTargeta() {
        return metricSalesByPaymentModeTargeta;
    }




    
    
    /**
     * Queries the data from the database and registres a Micrometer gauge meter
     * If no result is found registres a 0 value
     * @return
     */
    public List<SalesByPaymentModeDTO> registerMetricSalesByPaymentMode() {

        metricSalesByPaymentModeEfectiu = CALCULATION__CODE;
        metricSalesByPaymentModeTargeta = CALCULATION__CODE;

            this.registry.gauge(METRIC_NAME_SALES_BY_PAYMENT_MODE, Tags.of("PaymentModeName", PaymentMode.EFECTIU.getName()), getMetricSalesByPaymentModeEfectiu());
            this.registry.gauge(METRIC_NAME_SALES_BY_PAYMENT_MODE, Tags.of("PaymentModeName", PaymentMode.TARGETA_CREDIT.getName().replace(" ", "_")), getMetricSalesByPaymentModeTargeta());
    
        return salesByPaymentModeList;
        
    }
}
```

The method registerMetricSalesByPaymentMode is called by a resource endpoint periodically.

The result is that gauge values are not updated or don't appear.

The Quarkus documentation should show an example of this use case.(proposal)

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve by using builders in the constructor:

```
public OperationalMetricsBO(MeterRegistry registry){
        this.registry = registry;

        Gauge.builder(METRIC_NAME_SALES_BY_PAYMENT_MODE, this, OperationalMetricsBO::getMetricSalesByPaymentModeEfectiu)
            .tags(Tags.of("PaymentModeName", PaymentMode.EFECTIU.getName()))
                .register(this.registry);
        Gauge.builder(METRIC_NAME_SALES_BY_PAYMENT_MODE, this, OperationalMetricsBO::getMetricSalesByPaymentModeTargeta)
        .tags(Tags.of("PaymentModeName", PaymentMode.TARGETA_CREDIT.getName().replace(" ", "_")))
            .register(this.registry);
        
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, and is shown in the docs in several places: